# How do you write multiple lines in a YAML key?

Tags: yaml

Is it possible to have multi-line yaml as the key?

Here's my current multi-line yaml:

```
|
line one
line two
```

But this doesn't seem to work for when I make the above a key, like:

```
|
line one
line two:
  value
```

I've reviewed [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines) but I don't think it addresses exactly what I want to do.  Does anyone know of a good solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiline strings are "complex" yaml objects, so to use them as keys in a map, you need to use the `?`key`:` format:

```
? |
  line one
  line two
: value
```